# Extract text without header and footer with PDFBox

Tags: lucene, pdfbox

I use the PDFTextStripper class to extract pdf text before Lucene indexation.

Is there a possibility to exclude pdf header and footer from text extracted ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use text extraction by area if you know where exactly the header and footer are there in the document. Hope this helps.